# ICD-10 code prediction from unstructured clinical text

Tags: api, prediction, icd

Does anyone know of a prediction engine that produces ICD-10 diagnosis codes from unstructured clinical text? Preferably an API that I can work with.

The use case I have in mind is to pull doctors' notes from electronic health records systems (EHR) as inputs and produce ICD-10 diagnosis code options for users. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Diagnoss](https://www.diagnoss.com/) just put out [an API](https://api.diagnoss.com/docs/) that "tags" text with ICD-10 codes.  It is not predicting diagnoses, and you may need to filter the output depending on what you're looking for (specialty, accuracy, etc.). They've implemented it in a [demo](https://demo.diagnoss.com/).  I work for them -- happy to answer specific questions about it separately.